# Can I use Windows WinUSB without GUID?

Tags: winusb

I run some examples, finding that an interface GUID (from INF) is required to use winusb.
Is interface GUID used only under windows?
And can I use winusb without  GUID?

Lot of thanks in advance

Comment: It should be possible to enumerate all USB devices with `SetupDiGetClassDevs` (the GUID is optional) and then query additional information (such as vendor ID) to look for specific USB devices. Unlike on macOS, it doesnt' seem to be possible to query for specific vendor/product ID directly.